# alpakka s3 source cause akka stream to crash with TcpIdleTimeoutException: TCP idle-timeout encountered on connection

Tags: scala, amazon-s3, akka, akka-stream, alpakka

I am reading a file from S3 using alpakka s3 client

```
import akka.stream.alpakka.s3.scaladsl.S3
S3.download(bckt, bcktKey).flatMapConcat{
case Some((file, _)) =>
Foo
}.mapAsync(1){ f=> 
      Future{ Thread.sleep(1000)
}.recover{ 
e =>  e.printStackTrace}.to(Sink.ignore).run()
```

it crashes on

```
akka.stream.scaladsl.TcpIdleTimeoutException: TCP idle-timeout encountered on connection to [someBucket.s3.us-west-2.amazonaws.com:443], no bytes passed in the last 1 minute
```

It seems that the the source consumes the file fast and downstream the backpressure is consumed slowly and then the s3 connection closes and causes the stream to crash. Is there a way to tune S3 client timeout ?

update:
I did tried to use throttle at the end of the source but without success, getting the same problem